# Old error message keep popping up on IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

For some reason, anytime I try to import a python library, a particular old error message keeps popping up.

However, everything works fine when working with shell.

I know this is not a real programming question, but I'm stuck and would appreciate any help.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Error message**

```
>>> import nltk

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
    from internals import config_java
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 22, in <module>
    except ImportError: from xml.etree import ElementTree
ImportError: No module named etree
```

Comment: If you showed us what's that error, it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Is this a library you wrote or something that came with Python?

Comment: @Christian, I have included the error message. Burhan Khalid, it is an external library, it did not come with python. The error message surfaces whenever any external library is being imported.

Comment: Are you using the same Python installations?

Comment: @User, I understand what you mean by same python installations..can you please break it down? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py" exist in your computer?

Since IDLE and shell behaves differently, you may try the two lines in IDLE and Shell:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Then check the difference of env path

Comment: "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py" exist on my computer. Should I just remove it?

Comment: Don't remove it, there should be such a file. You may "import sys; sys.path" and paste your ENV paths here. Also you may try to reinstall you IDLE